# ¿Se recomienda tener 37 capas de salida en mi modelo a entrenar con tensorflow?

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, dataset, google-colab

Estoy tratando de entrenar una red neuronal que pueda identificar razas de perros/gatos con el dataset Oxford III de tensorflow, pero al momento del entrenamiento tengo un alto nivel de precisión en el entrenamiento, pero en la validación del entrenamiento no llega al 20%
estas serían mis capas de entrenamiento

```
modelo = tf.keras.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3,3), activation='relu', input_shape=(180, 180, 1)),
  tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2, 2),
  tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3,3), activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2, 2),
  tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(128, (3,3), activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2, 2),

  tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5),
  tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(250, activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(37,activation=tf.nn.softmax)#Para redes de clasificacion
])
```

mi compilacion:

```
modelo.compile(
    optimizer='adam',
    loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(),
    metrics=['accuracy']
)
modelo.summary()
historial = modelo.fit(X, y, epochs=100,validation_split=0.15)
```

```
Epoch 100/100
98/98 [==============================] - 4s 38ms/step - loss: 0.0156 - accuracy: 0.9962 - val_loss: 13.2959 - val_accuracy: 0.1196
```

Estoy usando la herramienta Colab de Google para esta tarea

Comment: Estás en Stack Overflow **en español**, podrías traducir tu pregunta o eliminarla y preguntar en el sitio en inglés por favor? De lo contrario terminará cerrada.

Comment: Traduce la pregunta completa, incluyendo el título.